# How can I iterate over an Array object by using For IN or FOR OF

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to print the details in format:
Key = Value,

However I get Undefined as the Valued.

```js
var customers = [{
    'custID': 123,
    'name': "ABC"
  },
  {
    'custID': 456,
    'name': "DEF"
  }
]

for (x of customers) {
  for (key in x) {
    console.log(key + " = " + customers[key])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `x` instead of `customers`,

- customers refers to original array and and `coustomers[key]` will be undefined as customers array donot have any key with name `custId or name`

```js
var customers = [{'custID': 123,'name': "ABC"},{'custID': 456,'name': "DEF"}]

for (x of customers) {
  for (key in x) {
    console.log(key + " = " + x[key])
  }
}
```

Or you can simply use `Object.entries`

```js
var customers = [{'custID': 123,'name': "ABC"}, {'custID': 456,'name': "DEF"}]


for (x of customers) {
  Object.entries(x).forEach(([key,value])=>{
    console.log(`${key} = ${value}`)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `x[key]`

```
for (x of customers)
{
    for(key in x)
    {
        console.log(key + " = " + x[key])
    }
}
```